# Plotting terra raster with white color set for 0 values

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I have a raster in `terra` that has values that ranges around 0.  I want my negative values to be blue and positive values to be red.  This question has already been ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140392/plot-raster-with-continuous-color-palette-with-zero-in-white-r-base) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295053/raster-color-positive-red-negative-blue), however the answer is for the `raster` package and do not apply for the `terra` package has there is no breakpoints argument.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
# preparing the session
library(terra)
library(magrittr)

# preparing the raster, I'm making sure my data go through 0 but are not centered at 0
set.seed(1234)
rr <- rast(matrix(rnorm(400, 1.5, 1), nrow=20, ncol=20))
```

Even if my values are not centered at 0, I want my color intensity to be centered at 0, to do so, I find the range that I need :

```
the_range <- range(values(rr)) %>% abs %>% max %>% multiply_by(c(-1,1))
```

Then I create my color palette:

```
the_palette_fc <- leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu", domain = the_range, reverse = T)
```

If I set, for example, 31 color classes to my map and plot it normally with terra I get:

```
plot(rr, col=the_palette_fc(seq(the_range[1], the_range[2], length.out=31)))
```

[image]

You can see that the white color was not fixed to the zero value.  Thats is probably because `terra::plot` calculate it's own range which is different from mine.

Reading around [online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435011/plotting-a-categorical-terra-raster-with-a-colour-map), I found a possible option which is to play with the `coltab` argument.  I tried it 2 ways:

```
coltab(rr) <- data.frame(
  val=seq(the_range[1], the_range[2], length.out=31),
  col=the_palette_fc(seq(the_range[1], the_range[2], length.out=31)))

plot(rr)
```

[image]

and:

```
coltab(rr) <- data.frame(
  val=values(rr),
  col=the_palette_fc(values(rr)))

plot(rr)
```

[image]

But the result do not seem to give the wanted results.  Also, there is no legend automatically added which is also necessary.  Maybe the coltab argument should be only used for categorical values?

So is there a way in `terra` to fined tune the colors palette so white is fix for 0 values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set 0  as the midpoint, you can set the domain of your palette to `c(-max(rr[]), max(rr[]))`:

```r
the_palette_fc <- leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu", 
                                        domain = c(-max(rr[]), max(rr[])),
                                        reverse = TRUE)

the_colors <- the_palette_fc(seq(min(rr[]), max(rr[]), length.out = 50))

plot(rr, col = the_colors)
```

[image]

If you want the scale to go from darkest blue to darkest red with a transition of white at 0, it is a bit more involved, but you could do:

```r
the_palette_fc <- leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu", 
                                        domain = c(-max(rr[]), max(rr[])),
                                        reverse = TRUE)

breakpoints <- seq(min(rr[]), max(rr[]), length.out = 50)

the_colors <- the_palette_fc(c(seq(-max(rr[]), 0, length = sum(breakpoints < 0)),
                              seq(0, max(rr[]), length = sum(breakpoints > 0))))

plot(rr, col = the_colors)
```

[image]

Comment: I was so close!  I guess I didn't properly understand the way palettes work.  Now I do, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`terra::plot` actually does have a "breaks" argument; but it is only documented in the examples so it was easy to overlook. You can do

```
library(terra)
set.seed(1234)
rr <- rast(matrix(rnorm(400, 1.5, 1), nrow=20, ncol=20))
ceil <- values(rr) |> abs() |> max() |> ceiling() 
pal <- leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = "RdBu", domain=c(-ceil, ceil), reverse = T)

b <- seq(-ceil, ceil, 1)
plot(rr, type="interval", breaks=b, col=pal(b))
```

[image]

In response to your comment:

For your purposes, you can also use the range argument, I think.

```
plot(rr, range=c(-ceil, ceil), col=pal(seq(-ceil,ceil,.1)))
```

[image]

And if you use "breaks", with terra 1.6-14 (currently the development version) you can now overwrite the default legend type.

```
plot(rr, type="cont", breaks=b, col=pal(b))
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice that the break argument was available, it works. However I don't like the way the legend change formats, it makes it too clutter in my actual code.  It's still a useful argument that I'll use for sure later on, thank you.

Comment: In that case, perhaps see the use of `range` in my expanded answer.

Comment: That is great, thanks.  However, is it normal that your last graph doesn't have color white associated to 0?

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Fixed now.