# Defining minimum and maximum for R terra color palette

Tags: r, terra

Title says all: I would like to plot a SpatRaster map using terra so that all values below a certain threshold have a color, all above another threshold have another color (say, all values below -2 are red and all values above 10 are blue), with a continuous palette in between. I can only find information on defining colors based on interval and class, but nothing for a continuous palette.

I tried something among the lines of the first answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624247](https://stackoverflow.com), but it doesn't quite apply to my situation.

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you have a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that might work for you.

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") 
r <- rast(f)
x <- clamp(r, 200, 400)
plot(x, plg=list(labels=c("< 200",250,300,400,"> 500")))
```